# Можно ли проверить поддерживает ли браузер шрифт ttf (TrueType)?

Tags: ttf, javascript

Возможно ли проверить поддерживает ли браузер шрифт ttf (TrueType), если не поддерживает, то выводить логотип картинкой, а не текстом. Потому как FireFox и IE похоже не дружат с ttf шрифтами...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему бы просто не прогнать шрифт через [шрифтобелку](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) или аналогичный генератор (например, http://everythingfonts.com/font-face), получить набор сгенерированных шрифтов и стили вроде таких

```
@font-face { /*HelveticaC Bold*/
font-family: 'HelveticaCBold';
src: url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/helveticac-bold.svg#HelveticaCBold') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

и подключить их к странице, чтобы нужный шрифт поддерживался во всех браузерах.